# Using main how do I pass a user entered value to its destination class

Tags: java

My assignment was to create the front end of an imaginary bank. The system asks the user for balance, and if they'd like to deposit or withdraw. In a separate class BankAccount.java I have declared `public static double balance;`. This is the value that holds the users' balance after they have entered it. This all works perfectly except for `bankAccount.balance = scanner.nextDouble();`. When the user enters their balance the program ends.

This is what the terminal outputs:

```
What is your current account balance :
10
Would you like to withdraw or deposit money through your account?

Process finished with exit code 0
```

For clarification, the opportunity to enter "withdraw" or "deposit" isn't actualized, the question is output as fast as the program ends.

I've marked the line causing me grief with //<-- PROBLEM LINE

```
public class Bank
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //System.out.println( "" );
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
        BankAccount bankAccount = new BankAccount();

        System.out.println( "What is your current account balance :" );
        bankAccount.balance = scanner.nextDouble(); //<-- PROBLEM LINE

        System.out.println("Would you like to withdraw or deposit money through your account?");

        String choice = scanner.nextLine();

        if ( choice.equals( "deposit" ) )
        {
            System.out.println("How much money would you like to deposit?");
            bankAccount.deposit(scanner.nextDouble());
        }
        if ( choice.equals( "withdraw" ) )
        {
            System.out.println( "How much money would you like to withdraw?" );
            try
            {
                System.out.println( "Your new account balance is : $" + bankAccount.withdraw(scanner.nextDouble()) );
            }
            catch ( NotEnoughBalanceException e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and ... what exactly is the problem? Pointing out where the problem occurs without mentioning what the problem is won't help us much understanding it. Also: why would 'balance' be static? That makes no sense at all, unless you think there is only one BankAccount in the world

Comment: probably, it raises an issue because you are using a static variable as if it's an instance variable. Even though that's terribly bad design, it should work.

Comment: @Stultuske Sentence 6 of my question mentions my problem. Also if you read the entire question you'd see how the terminal output isn't logically matching what it should be (and otherwise would be) if not for the "problem line", hence why I labeled that line. Which I clarify in sentence 8 of my question. I made balance static because of someone's answer on this website on a different question.

Comment: The output you’ve put implies you hit enter after it said put ‘withdraw’ or ‘deposit’. In this case neither of your if statements get entered and the program exits normally (exit code 0)…

Comment: @Stultuske changing it from static to "public double balance;" yields the same result.

Comment: @Jovaphobic no, that sentence contains a crude and vague description. It should be a private double balance, with setter and getter, and a constructor for the class. Most likely, you are having trouble with which Scanner method consumes an enter and which not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the scanner.nextLine() and if you need a double just parse it.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //System.out.println( "" );
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        BankAccount bankAccount = new BankAccount();

        System.out.println("What is your current account balance :");
        bankAccount.balance = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine()); //<-- PROBLEM LINE

        System.out.println("Would you like to withdraw or deposit money through your account?");
        String choice = scanner.nextLine();

        if (choice.equals("deposit")) {
            System.out.println("How much money would you like to deposit?");
            bankAccount.deposit(Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine()));
        }
        if (choice.equals("withdraw")) {
            System.out.println("How much money would you like to withdraw?");
            try {
                System.out.println("Your new account balance is : $" + bankAccount.withdraw(Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine())));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is nextDouble() doesn't actually consume the newline from you pressing enter, so scanner.nextLine() returns immediately, returning an empty line. You could use nextLine() instead of nextDouble() and use the Double class to parse the result, like so:

```
bankAccount.balance = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
```